# Bubble sort not working as expected C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I wrote a simple bubble sorting algorithm, however it is returning strange results when ran...

I am attempting to sort parallel vectors (not sure if that is correct terminology, I'm taking the concept of parallel arrays and applying it to vectors so I can modify the size at runtime) that make up a contact list.

The code pertaining to the vectors and bubble sort:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector <long long int> numbers;
    vector <string> names;

    names.push_back("jack");
    numbers.push_back(6515551234);
    names.push_back("jill");
    numbers.push_back(6515554321);
    names.push_back("bob");
    numbers.push_back(6515557777);
    names.push_back("aaron");
    numbers.push_back(6665559999);
    names.push_back("fred");
    numbers.push_back(1115552222);

    int index = -1;
    long int temp = -1;
    int pass = -1;
    string tempName;
    int sortChoice;

    for (pass = 0; pass < names.size(); pass++) {
        for (index = 0; index < names.size() - pass; index++) {
            if ( names[index] > names[index + 1] ) {


            temp = numbers[index]; 
            numbers[index] = numbers[index + 1]; 
            numbers[index + 1] = temp; 

            tempName = names[index];
            names[index] = names[index + 1];
            names[index + 1] = tempName;

            }
        }
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
       cout << names[i] << ": " << numbers[i] << endl;
   }

    return 0;

}
```

And the output:

```
: 465675315720                                                                                                                                  
aaron: 6665559999                                                                                                                               
bob: 6515557777                                                                                                                                 
fred: 1115552222                                                                                                                                
jack: 6515551234
```

And it seems that no matter how I change the vectors themselves, the last one is always cut off, and put at the beginning with no name and a (seemingly) random number. Has anyone seen this before?

The only thing I can think of is that while the sort is processing, something goes awry in memory, causing pointing to incorrect memory locations?... And the fact that it is always the last element makes me think the issue pertains to the last iteration of the loop.

Also, I made a version of this to sort by numbers rather than names, and it works perfectly every time. It's the same code but using numbers[index] in place of names[index] in the algorithm loop.

P.S. - I'm still rather new to StackOverflow and coding in general, so if I made any mistakes in formatting this post let me know and I will change them. And I hope I provided enough information.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: this is not bubble sort ...

Comment: You are both correct, I don't really have any knowledge regarding debuggers. I will be sure to read the article you guys linked and walk through my code. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the code that you have written above is **not** bubble sort !

however , try this instead , this is bubble sort:

```
for (pass = 0; pass < names.size(); pass++) {
        for (index = pass+1; index < names.size(); index++) {
            if ( names[pass] > names[index] ) {


            temp = numbers[index]; 
            numbers[index] = numbers[pass]; 
            numbers[pass] = temp; 

            tempName = names[index];
            names[index] = names[pass];
            names[pass] = tempName;

            }
        }
   }
```

i offer you use a [`pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) instead of two vectors

Comment: Could anyone expand on why my code isn't a bubble sort? I tried this code in my program and it seems to work however - so I will be going back through my original code with a debugger as suggested, as well as stepping through this to find the differences. Thank you!

Comment: this is **Insertion sort**, this is work, but it is not bubble sort

Comment: the first loop should from 0 to  names.size() - 1

Comment: @YuJing this is not **insertion sort** , i think you need to review sorting algorithms , look [here](http://cforbeginners.com/insertionsort.html)

Comment: @YuJing i don't know who upvoted your comment , but look at my condition : `pas = 0 ; pass < names.size()` it means `0` to `names.size()-1`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I mean (pass = 0; pass < (names.size() - 1); pass++), please think again, what if pass == (names.size() - 1) , index == names.size(), and directly index >= names.size()

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi these are fundamental things

Comment: additionally, at least, this is NOT bubble sort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort ,  Starting from the beginning of the list, compare every **adjacent pair**, swap their position if they are not in the right order

Comment: thanks for helping me review my books, this is Selection Sort, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort , please have a look at the example code, and tell me again, are you wrong?

Comment: @YuJing my code is bubble sort , i'm not gonna prove it to you , i can't realize why you are showing such resistance , i'm not gonna prove myself to you , it the most simple thing ever , i will not dicuss it again

Answer (score 0):

for each loop, you should compare each neighborhood, from the first to the end.

your error:

> for (index = 0; index < names.size() - pass; index++) {

should be

> for (index = 0; index < names.size() - 1; index++) {

here is a sample

start: 5 4 3 2 1

loop: 0

index: 0 : [5 4] 3 2 1   =>   [4 5] 3 2 1

index: 1 :4  [5 3] 2 1   =>  4  [3 5] 2 1

index: 2 :4 3  [5 2] 1   =>  4 3  [2 5] 1

index: 3 :4 3 2  [5 1]   =>  4 3 2  [1 5]

loop: 1

index: 0 : [4 3] 2 1 5   =>   [3 4] 2 1 5

index: 1 :3  [4 2] 1 5   =>  3  [2 4] 1 5

index: 2 :3 2  [4 1] 5   =>  3 2  [1 4] 5

index: 3 :3 2 1  [4 5]   =>  3 2 1  [4 5]

loop: 2

index: 0 : [3 2] 1 4 5   =>   [2 3] 1 4 5

index: 1 :2  [3 1] 4 5   =>  2  [1 3] 4 5

index: 2 :2 1  [3 4] 5   =>  2 1  [3 4] 5

index: 3 :2 1 3  [4 5]   =>  2 1 3  [4 5]

loop: 3

index: 0 : [2 1] 3 4 5   =>   [1 2] 3 4 5

index: 1 :1  [2 3] 4 5   =>  1  [2 3] 4 5

index: 2 :1 2  [3 4] 5   =>  1 2  [3 4] 5

index: 3 :1 2 3  [4 5]   =>  1 2 3  [4 5]

loop: 4

index: 0 : [1 2] 3 4 5   =>   [1 2] 3 4 5

index: 1 :1  [2 3] 4 5   =>  1  [2 3] 4 5

index: 2 :1 2  [3 4] 5   =>  1 2  [3 4] 5

index: 3 :1 2 3  [4 5]   =>  1 2 3  [4 5]

final result: 1 2 3 4 5